# Android library with dependences for Unity 3d

Tags: android-studio, unity-game-engine, android-library

I'm building an android library for Unity3d. This library is developing in Android Studio and I'm using some modules like google admob. For this, I added 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0' to the gradle file.
The problem is that when I build the Unity3d project, the app crashes because does not find an admob class:

Here is the log

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.-----, PID: 8280
java.lang.Error: FATAL EXCEPTION [main]
Unity version     : 5.3.2f1
Device model      : htc Nexus 9
Device fingerprint: google/volantis/flounder:6.0.1/MMB29V/2554798:user/release-keys
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdView;
.....
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView" on path: DexPathList
```

This is my library's gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
   compileSdkVersion 23
   buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
 compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'], exclude: ['classes.jar'])
 testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
 provided files('libs/classes.jar')
}
```

Is there a way to create an android library with dependencies to put it in Unity without put the sdks that I'm using in this library?. I mean, I want to build my library with all the sdks that I'm using and put only my library in Unity3d.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to put all needed libraries manually to Assets/Plugins/Android.
Or you can try to fork https://github.com/googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver and add support of your library...